# Connect database internally

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have [three tables](http://puu.sh/lTNGq/320fd6af2e.png) in database.

1-quotes

2-types

3-authors

In quotes table, I had assigned type_id which is primary key in types table also author_id which is primary key for authors table.

Now when i want to echo one quote in one time in this format.

```
"When you get to my age life seems little more than one long march to 
and from the lavatory."

 By: A. C. Benson   Category: age
```

So how to connect this data-base to get this type of output?

I tried this but it only outputs quote.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes LIMIT 1";
 $result = $con->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo  " \" " . $row["quote"].  "\"<br><br>";
 }
```

Comment: Are category and type the same terms in your code/database? And also, can you show the structure of quotes table?

Comment: Yes category means type and i had linked image http://puu.sh/lTNGq/320fd6af2e.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a JOIN clause to connect the output from your quotes with the types and authors.

This could for example look like this if every quote has a field type_id and author_id to link to the other tables.

```
SELECT * FROM quotes JOIN types ON quotes.type_id = types.id JOIN authors ON quotes.author_id = author.id
```

In PHP this could look as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quotes JOIN types ON quotes.type_id = types.id JOIN authors ON quotes.author_id = authors.id";
 $result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo  " \" " . $row["quote"].  "\"<br>".$row["author"]." ".$row["type"] ."<br>";
 }
```

when your tables look like this:

```
quotes:
id, quote, author_id, type_id

types:
id, type

authors:
id, author
```

Comment: You can then use all row names of each of the joined tables in your `$row["column_name"]`. If they have the same names e.g. author has a "name" column and quote has a "name" column you can use an ALIAS.

Comment: You could also try to use an alias
`SELECT quotes.quote, authors.author AS author_name, types.type AS type_name FROM quotes JOIN types ON quotes.type_id = types.id JOIN authors ON quotes.author_id = authors.id` and then try `$row["author_name"]`

Comment: Everythings is fine in SQL when I run query in phpmy admin its perfect.

But in my php file its giving out error. :(

http://puu.sh/lTQFe/246132deac.png
http://puu.sh/lTQGg/44b66bad6d.png

http://puu.sh/lTQIJ/d6b8cc5e19.png

Comment: hmm, you could try to use `fetch_array` instead of `fetch_assoc` but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: You can list the column names with fetch-field, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php perhaps this can show you if the columns arrive at the php side